# What's the Best Practice for Continuous Streaming Termination with GRPC Service (C++)

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-c++

Consider an rpc service which continuously streams a response from server to client:

```
rpc stream_stuff(MyStreamRequest) returns (stream MyStreamResponse);
```

The Request contains data which specifies how much data to send and how often, including an option to stream for an unspecified amount of time.

The `ClientContext` object provides a `TryCancel()` method which allows for a best effort attempt to cancel the rpc.  This works to first order.  However the docs are emphatic that this might not always work.

Is `TryCancel()` the standard way this is handled or should I build cancellation into the service somehow (e.g. via multidirectional stream which the server checks for cancellation)?

If neither, what is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: There is a [response in the official gRPC repo](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/17292#issuecomment-460773219) that `TryCancel()` is the "right way to cancel a stream" (without further info) if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks @dan-kli.  Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I added it as an answer. You said "However the docs are emphatic that this might not always work.", I wonder in which cases it might not work. When the cancellation request sent by the client does not arrive on the server? In what other scenario it might not work?

Comment: I think that's a great question.  Not sure it will get any play on SO but might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [response in the official gRPC repo](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/17292#issuecomment-460773219) by one of the developers that `TryCancel()` is "the right way to cancel a stream".